# Dynamic Routing in REACT.js using data fetched from an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have been working on a complex application using REACT.js for the past few months and have run into a problem that I have been unable to solve despite extensive research and experimentation.

The issue is that I am trying to implement dynamic routing in my application, where the routes are determined by data that is fetched from an API. I have been using the react-router-dom library to handle my routing, and have successfully implemented static routes. However, when I try to use dynamic routes based on the data fetched from the API, the application throws an error.

I have tried several different approaches to resolving this issue, including using the useEffect hook to fetch the data and update the routes, and also using a library such as react-dynamic-route to handle the dynamic routing. However, I have not been able to get any of these approaches to work.

Here is an example of the code I am currently using to fetch the data and update the routes:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { fetchData } from './api';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  useLocation
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAPI = async () => {
      setData(await fetchData());
    };
    fetchAPI();
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {data.map((item) => (
          <Route key={item.id} path={`/${item.id}`} component={DetailPage} />
        ))}
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

export default App;
I would greatly appreciate any insight or advice on how to properly implement dynamic routing in a REACT.js application using data fetched from an API. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy this code from an old website post or something? I'm quite sure that switch doesn't exist anymore. There are other things as well that seems weird but if this was just copied from some old post i can give an example of how it could be written instead so that it might work

Answer (score 0):

There are several things in your code that I believe are incorrect. Firstly `Switch` is outdated, if you are using an older version of `react-router-dom` you may be able yo use it, instead use `Routes`. The `component` attribute was deprecated before v5.1 I believe and cannot be used in newer versions of react, instead use the `element` attribute. Also it is important to note that this attribute need to have the name in tags.

```
<Route
    key={item.id}
    path={`/${item.id}`}
    element={<DetailPage />}
/>
```

Also `useLocation` may only be used in the context of a router, meaning that it can be used in one of the element that you are routing to but unless you have a route for the `App` component it's not going to work.
I've made a small example to show what your code could look like to make it work.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/testItems')
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => setData(res));
    }, []);

    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                {data.map((item: { id: number; idk: string }) => (
                    <Route
                        key={item.id}
                        path={`/${item.id}`}
                        element={<Comp />}
                    />
                ))}
                <Route element={<p>This seems wrong</p>} />
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;

function Comp() {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
}
```

I've tested the code with a local server for the fetch. The server has the following data.

```
{
    "testItems": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "idk": "other stuff"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "idk": "not good at naming stuff"
        }
    ]
}
```